# how to get index of chart in multiple highchart container

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I have 5 charts in a single page, I'm not getting the current chart index, because I'm writing label name on 5th chart(in another page it will be in different position like 2nd or 3rd). Now manually mentioning as "Highcharts.charts[0]", instead of "0", I want values. thanks in advance.

```
formatter: function () {
    var name =  Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].categories[this.x];
    return "<b>" + name + "<br/>" + "<b>$" + this.total + "<br/> per annum";
}
```

Comment: So on a single page, you have 5 highchart elements, and you need a way to name them? like "myChart.xAxis[0]" ?

Comment: yes, i have 5 charts in a single page, i need 5th one(stacked chart) in some other page it will be in 2nd position, i'm using chartbase in different file.

Answer (score 2):

You can select charts, for example, through their containers  `id`.

```
$("#firstChartContainer").highcharts(/*options*/)

var firstChart = $("#firstChartContainer").highcharts();

firstChart.xAxis....
```